# unlink or rmdir cant remove folder.only remove file in folder

Tags: php, unlink, rmdir

i have file in upload/project1/update.

the problem is,only files in update is deleted. i want to remove the directory in folder upload...thats mean,folder name 'project1' and 'update' also delete after the files in update is deleted.can u spots the mistakes for me??

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$filename = $_GET['filename']; //gets the file name eg:update.zip
$fname = $_GET['fname']; //gets the folder name eg: project1
$upload = "upload/";

$name = explode(".", $filename);
$folder = $fname."/".$name[0];

$files = glob($upload.$folder.'/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file)
{ // iterate files
if(is_file($file))
 unlink($file); // delete file dlm folder

}

closedir($name[0]); //close update dir
rmdir($name[0]); //remove update dir
```

this coding give warning

> Warning: closedir() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>
> Warning: rmdir(update) [function.rmdir]: No such file or directory..

but in the directory upload,have this file project1/update.

also,the filename is 'update.zip' is just the name in database only..not in the directory.

Comment: The directory path that is to be opened. did you open your directory? using for ex: `$dh = opendir($dir)`.

Comment: is still need to open directory after using glob to get the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `closedir()` on a directory that has not previously been opened (and stored in a filehandle) with the `opendir()` PHP function. If you want to `closedir()` you will need to get a filehandle to this directory first using `opendir()`. This is per the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php

Additionally, if you want to `rmdir()` a directory, it needs to be completely empty and you need the appropriate permissions. Otherwise, you will get errors. This is also per the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

Comment: Once you get a directory filehandle, then you can "closedir()" on it and your script will then proceed past its original error on to rmdir(). Please don't forget to accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: after closedir, still get warning in my rmdir($folder);Warning: rmdir(project1/update) [function.rmdir]: No such file or directory

Comment: Look at your error message: Check to make sure you are including the FULL PATH ("/uploads/project1/update" and not simply "project1/update").

Comment: now,there's no warning,but only the folder name update is deleted,not the project1.is it posibble if have two rmdir? like rmdir($dir); rmdir($fname);  ?

Comment: Yes certainly. Just put one after the other.